# Convert np array of arrays to torch tensor when inner arrays are of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have several videos, which I have loaded frame by frame into a numpy array of arrays. For example if I have 8 videos, they are converted into an 8 dimensional numpy array of arrays where each inner array has a different dimension depending on the number of frames of the individual video. When I print

```
array.shape
```

my output is (8,)

Now I would like to create a dataloader for this data, and for that I would like to convert this numpy array into a torch tensor. However when I try to convert it using the `torch.from_numpy` or even simply the `torch.tensor` functions I get the error

```
TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.
```

which I assume is because my inner arrays are of different sizes. One possible solution is to artificially add a dimension to my videos to make them be of the same size and then use `np.stack` but that may lead to possible problems later on. Is there any better solution?

Edit: Actually adding a dimension won't work because np.stack requires all dimensions to be the same.

Edit: Sample Array would be something like:

```
[ [1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4] ]
```

This is stored as a (3,) shaped np array. The real arrays are actually 4-dimensional( Frames x Height x Width x Channels), so this is just an example.

Comment: Please Add sample array.

Comment: One option is to adjust all sizes to be the same by padding with zeros. Second and in my opinion better way is just create separate tensor for each video and store them in a list.

Comment: @V.Ayrat Yeah for the moment I guess I am going to create a list and then use a dataloader on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rnn` util function [`pad_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#pad-sequence) to make them same size.

```
ary
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([1, 2]), list([1, 2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)

from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
t = pad_sequence([torch.tensor(x) for x in ary], batch_first=True)

t
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 0],
        [1, 2, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]])
t.shape
torch.Size([3, 4])
```

Comment: This would work fine in most cases, however I would like to avoid having to modify my images in any way before passing into the network, apart from normalization.